# htaccess rewrite only if specific file doesn't exist

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For the following example how do I use **RewriteCond** and **RewriteRule** if only 1 specific file does not exist, for example:

I have **htps://a.b.com/sw.js**, if it exist then do nothing.
If **htps://a.b.com/sw.js** doesn't exist then check in **htps://a.b.com/folder1/sw.js**, or **htps://a.b.com/folder2/sw.js**. If it does exist in let say **htps://a.b.com/folder2/sw.js**, then rewrite **htps://a.b.com/sw.js** to **htps://a.b.com/folder2/sw.js**

All i have is:

```
RewriteCond https://a.b.com/sw.js # exist so do nothing

RewriteCond https://a.b.com/sw.js -f # does not exist
RewriteCond https://a.b.com/folder1/sw.js -f # check if it's in folder 1 (assume it's not)
RewriteCond https://a.b.com/folder2/sw.js -f # check if it's in folder 2 (assume it is)
RewriteRule https://a.b.com/sw.js shows code from https://a.b.com/folder2/sw.js
```

Comment: You will need to use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to check if it does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if what you attempt to implement is a good strategy. *Guessing* what resource might be requested smells of a very unstable setup. You really should try to be specific in references you hand out and what requests you want to server or don't want to serve. Otherwise you risk running into various strange issues that are hard to debug, since you never really know the dependency between resources.

Anyway, here is a suggestion for a rewriting approach:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [PT,END]

RewriteCond /folder1%/{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ /folder1/$1 [END]

RewriteCond /folder2%/{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ /folder2/$1 [END]
```

In case you receive a http status 500 with this setup, then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. In that case try replacing the `END` flag with the `L` flag...

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).